# Angular 6 rest call after for loop with nested rest calls

Tags: angular, rest, for-loop

I've a problem solving following situation... very complicated for me. I've a for loop in which I need to conditionally call 3 nested http requests and, at the end of loop, call another http request.

```
for(let elem in myElemsArray) {
    if(this.addMessage) {
        this.service.addMessage(elem).pipe(
            concatMap(resp => {
                 return this.service.updateMessageList(resp)
            }),
            map(data=> {
                 return this.service.getMessageList(data.idList)
            })
        ).subscribe(list => this.showList())
    } else {
        this.service.closeList().subscribe(resp => .... do something ....)
    }
}

//At the end of loop, I need to reuse myElemsArray but only if all iterations are completed!

this.service.closeAllMessages().subscribe(
    .... do something ....
);
```

Is there a right way to do this? Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: It seems you are not doing anything with `elem`, is that correct? When do you want `this.showList()` to happen? After every http call or when all calls are complete?

Comment: I modified to use elem in addMessage(). Anyway this is a sort of example code, just to show you what I want to do. I want to call showList() on every iteration and closeAllMessages() when all calls and the loop are complete.

Comment: It's bad practice to call API in loop. Please do some RND on `rxjs` and it's feature `forkjoin`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make multiple calls, rxjs forkjoin is your friends.
It takes an array of observables as a parameter, and completes only when all the observables have completed.

If you need to execute some code only when all observables are completed, you should use the loop only to create the parameters to send to forkjoin. The call forkjoin with it and wait for its answer to complete your code